# django Записи пользователя

Tags: python, django, авторизация

как сделать так что бы при авторизации пользователя,  пользователь видел записи связаны столько сним проект на django и как правильно простроить url адрес
файл views

```
class RecordsView(ListView):
    model = Records
    template_name = 'records/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'records'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Records.objects.filter(is_done=False, account=self.request.account)

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'Главная'
    return context
```

файл models

```
class Records(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=56, verbose_name='Наименование')
    quantity = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Количество")
    money = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сумма')
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
           verbose_name='Пользователь')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('index', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.money}'

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Запись"
    verbose_name_plural = "Записи"
    ordering = ['-date']
```

файл urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', index, name='home'),
path('accounts/<int:account_id>/', RecordsView.as_view(), name='records'),
path('accounts/register/', register, name='register'),
path('accounts/login/', user_login, name='login'),
path('accounts/logout/', user_logout, name='logout'),
path('accounts/contact/', contact, name='contact'),
```

]